# How to re-render a directive template and link function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am creating a navigation "tree" that basically allows you to navigate to parent views like so

`Home > Planner > Contacts > john.smith@hotmail.com`

This list is just a normal `<ul>` that should get changed each time the view is changed and allow the user to click on any of the above links to navigate.  I am using `ui-router`'s `$stateChangeStart` event to build up my list of links, the problem is that my directive does not "re-build" this list every time the page change.

Is there a way to force the directive to re-render every time I change my state?

**TreeNav directive**

```
app.directive('treeNav', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<ul>\
                    <li ng-repeat="item in treeNavs">\
                        <a ui-sref="{{ item.state }}">{{ item.name }}</a>\
                        <span> > </span>\
                    </li>\
                   </ul>',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.treeNavs = $rootScope.treeNav.reverse();

                scope.$watch('$rootScope.treeNav', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                scope.treeNavs = newVal.reverse();
                });
            }

        }

    }]);
```

Comment: actually I guess the correct way to do this is to just use $apply or $watch on `$rootScope.treeNav` in order to check when it changes

Comment: Matt, yes you have two ways to do this, either $watch $rootScope.treeNav, or use events (emit/broadcast/on) to notify when treeNav changes.

Comment: Ok, I updated my code to try a $watch, but now my directive is just not showing at all.. I think I am doing something wrong

Comment: `After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.` I suspect this is what is happening. Just add the necessary check inside watch before you set the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you aren't setting up your `$watch` statement correctly.

You should also be careful with your use of `.reverse`. `reverse()` reverses the entries in an array *in place*, which is probably not what you want to do, since it would modify the array on the `$rootScope`.

You can use `splice()` to create a new copy and then reverse that:

```
scope.treeNavs = $rootScope.treeNavs.splice().reverse();
$rootScope.$watch('treeNav', function(newVal) {
  scope.treeNavs = newVal.splice().reverse();
});
```